# centos 5 + nginx + git-http-backend

Tags: centos, git, nginx

I've a CentOS 5 server at domain.fr. I'm trying to set a subdomain so that I can use it with git, "git.domain.fr".

- My repositories are in `/home/git` (example `/home/git/repos.git`).
- I've installed `git-http-backend and nginx`.
- I've set a repository like this: `cd /home/git/repos.git && git --bare init`.
- I've set my `git.conf` (included in `nginx.conf`) as below.

However, on my client shell, I get the fatal error "repository not found":

```
$ git clone http://git.domain.fr/repos.git
```

Does anyone know what I should do? It seems so simple, I'm getting frustrated because I'm sure it's nothing...

```
server {

    listen          80;
    server_name     git.domain.fr;
    root            /home/git;

    location ~ /(/.*) {

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/bin/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL     true;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT        /home/git;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
}
```

#### EDIT #1

I've updated the file as this:

```
server  {

    listen          80;
    server_name     git.domain.fr;
    root            /home/git;

    access_log /var/log/httpd/git.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/httpd/git.error.log;

    location / {

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/bin/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL     true;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT        /home/git;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $uri;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/src/fcgiwrap/systemd/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
}
```

I also checked the socket location and gave it to `nginx:nginx`, but I'm now getting an "Error 500".

```
$ git clone git.domain.fr/repos.git
Cloning into 'repos'...
fatal: unable to access 'git.domain.fr/repos.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

fcgi wrap is running:

```
$ netstat -anp | grep cgi
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1510861 24878/fcgiwrap      /usr/local/src/fcgiwrap/systemd/fcgiwrap.socket
```

It has the correct permissions:

```
$ ls -lia /usr/local/src/fcgiwrap/systemd/fcgiwrap.socket
3067341 srwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx 0 févr. 22 23:51 /usr/local/src/fcgiwrap/systemd/fcgiwrap.socket
```

`git.error.log` is empty, but `git.access.log` contains:

```
1**.***.***.*** - - [23/Feb/2014:13:02:17 +0100] "GET /repos.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "git/1.8.4"
```

#### EDIT #2

Problem almost solved : I just restarted my server for some reasons, then `git pull` worked.

Now, I am getting a 403 error when I push.

Push :

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin master
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fe329811800
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fe329811800) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to git.domain.fr port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 108.162.199.22...
* Connected to git.domain.fr (108.162.199.22) port 80 (#0)
> GET /repos.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.8.4
Host: git.domain.fr
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
* Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< Date: Sun, 23 Feb 2014 18:20:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dc7d61cac342494e2b1307f88f8bf440f1393179659791; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.fr; HttpOnly
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< CF-RAY: 1015eee9b29a091a-CDG
< 
* Connection #0 to host git.domain.fr left intact
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.domain.fr/repos.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Pull :

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git pull origin master
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fb11b811800
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fb11b811800) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to git.domain.fr port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 108.162.198.22...
* Connected to git.domain.fr (108.162.198.22) port 80 (#0)
> GET /repos.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.8.4
Host: git.domain.fr
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< Date: Sun, 23 Feb 2014 18:25:33 GMT
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d75ab90529a399f012383cdee482bc7ed1393179933224; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.fr; HttpOnly
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< CF-RAY: 1015f596a8700914-CDG
< 
* Connection #0 to host git.domain.fr left intact
From http://git.domain.fr/repos
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Log (error.log is empty) :

```
$ tail -f /var/log/httpd/git.access.log 
1**.***.***.*** - - [23/Feb/2014:19:20:59 +0100] "GET /repos.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 5 "-" "git/1.8.4"
1**.***.***.*** - - [23/Feb/2014:19:25:33 +0100] "GET /repos.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 294 "-" "git/1.8.4"
```

I checked the rights and owners. What can I do ? Any idea ?

#### EDIT #3

SUCCESS !

Git push gets a 403 errors when you use it without authentication. I just had to set nginx so that it asks for a user/password :

```
server  {

    listen          80;
        server_name     git.domain.fr;
        root            /home/git;

        access_log /var/log/httpd/git.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/httpd/git.error.log;

        auth_basic          "Accès restreint";
        auth_basic_user_file    /home/domain.fr/git_access;

        location / {

                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         /usr/bin/git-http-backend;
                fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL     true;
                fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT        /home/git;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $uri;
                fastcgi_param   REMOTE_USER         $remote_user;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/src/fcgiwrap/systemd/fcgiwrap.socket;
        }
}
```

You should also check that your repository belongs to `git:git` :

```
chmod -R g+ws repos.git
chgrp -R git repos.git
```

Everything's fine now.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I just learned that the last two `chmod` and `chgrp` commands are very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your location match URIs starting with two slashes which is impossible with default nginx configuration. Also there is no need to have regexp location, if you want proxy all requests. This one should work for you:

```
location / {

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/bin/git-http-backend;
    fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL     true;
    fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT        /home/git;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
}
```

Comment: Also I've changed PATH_INFO

Comment: Post updated. It's almost ok. It's now only about an error 500.

Comment: Edit #2. Almost done, but error 403 as I push.

Comment: I guess, you should properly setup git-http-backend, but I can't help you with that. Sorry

Comment: I solved it, finally =)

Comment: In case you're curious, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40313590/107158 illustrates how to configure `git-http-backend` to enable  *anonymous read access but authenticated write access*.